# JavaScript - Array passed by reference but lost when reassigned

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

In the following JS code, why doesn't `f3(arr2)` change the value of `arr2` like `f2(arr1)` did to `arr1`? Is there any way to make `f3` work as expected (if possible, without returning the modified array)?

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function f1() {
    return [2, 3, 4, 5];
}

function f2(arr) {
    arr.push(5);
}

function f3(arr) {
    arr = f1();
}

f2(arr1);
console.log(arr1); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

f3(arr2);
console.log(arr2); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], expect [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: arr in f3 is just a reference, you should `splice` or use similar `Array.prototype` method to change the array it references.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify the array, then you actually have to modify the array. You can't just write a reference to a different array over the variable (as that just throws away the local reference to that array).

```
function f3(arr) {
    arr.length = 0; // Empty the array
    f1().forEach(function (currentValue) { arr.push(currentValue); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

quote: "console.log(arr2); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], **expect** [2, 3, 4, 5]"

The reason that you are not getting what you are expecting is this part here

`function f3(*arr*) {  *arr* = f1(); }`

You are assigning the array [2,3,4,5] to the argument-name ***arr*** of the function ***f3***, not to the arr2. Arr2 remains of course untouched and in its original state throughout your script.

`function f3(*arr*) {  *arr2* = f1(); }` will do it.

But this answer is not my final. This is only how it appears.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a single step:

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, [0, arr.length].concat(f1()));
```

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function f1() {
    return [2, 3, 4, 5];
}

function f2(arr) {
    arr.push(5);
}

function f3(arr) {
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, [0, arr.length].concat(f1()));
}

f2(arr1);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

f3(arr2);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: this is not what op was asking

Comment: @BekimBacaj, what is op expecting/asking?

Comment: as it seems, he is expecting a JavaScript object being assigned to a (local) variable name of the function argument (arr), to be reflected in the pointing direction that his global arr2 is pointing at. And he's asking why?
The answer is: your local pointer has no way of changing the pointing direction of the one it learnt it from.  Because arr2 is simply telling to the local arr where is the [1,2,3,4] object. You can't change the source of information by changing the content of the carrier.

Answer (score -1):

When you pass anything (Whether that be an object or a primitive), all javascript does is assign a new variable while inside the function... just like using the equal sign (=)

How that parameter behaves inside the function is exactly the same as it would behave if you just assigned a new variable using the equal sign.. Take these simple examples.
You can ref: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)